How to fill missing values based on relationships between existing data
Question
How to fill missing values of a pandas dataframe based on the relationship between an existing preceeding row (predictions for a commodity), and an associated existing value in another column (actual values for a commodity).
Details
I have a pandas dataframe with 10 columns and 40 rows. The columns are Date, Actual, time_from_actual_1, time_from_actual_2, time_from_actual_3... up to time_from_actual_8.
The Actual column contains actual values for a commodity with hourly timestamps in the Date column. The time_from_actual columns are predictions forward in time for the same commodity. These are produced once per day, hence the pre-existing values at Index 0 and Index 1. And so, there are 23 missing observations per day.
Input dataframe

I would like to fill those missing values in a very specific way. I want the values for "time_from_actual" at index 1 up to 24 to follow the same pattern as the first column with regards to the differences between the different timesteps and the actual values.
Output dataframe

I've succeeded doing this with a nested for loop, but I would very much like to see suggestions for more elegant approaches. Below you will find a complete attempt with sample data, code and output. Thank you for any suggestions!
Code
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Random seed
np.random.seed(42)

# Sample data
data = {
    'Date': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=40, freq='H'),
    'Actual': [100, 99.72, 101.02, 104.06, 103.60, 103.13, 106.29, 107.82, 106.88, 107.97,
               107.04, 106.11, 106.59, 102.77, 99.32, 98.19, 96.17, 96.80, 94.98, 92.15,
               95.09, 94.63, 94.77, 91.92, 90.83, 91.05, 88.75, 89.50, 88.30, 87.72,
               86.51, 90.22, 90.19, 88.08, 89.72, 87.28, 87.70, 83.78, 81.12, 131.52],
    'time_from_actual_1': [97] + [np.nan]*23 + [90] + [np.nan]*15,
    'time_from_actual_2': [99] + [np.nan]*23 + [89] + [np.nan]*15,
    'time_from_actual_3': [98] + [np.nan]*23 + [88] + [np.nan]*15,
    'time_from_actual_4': [97] + [np.nan]*23 + [87] + [np.nan]*15,
    'time_from_actual_5': [96] + [np.nan]*23 + [86] + [np.nan]*15,
    'time_from_actual_6': [95] + [np.nan]*23 + [85] + [np.nan]*15,
    'time_from_actual_7': [94] + [np.nan]*23 + [84] + [np.nan]*15,
    'time_from_actual_8': [93] + [np.nan]*23 + [83] + [np.nan]*15,
}

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# copy of the dataframe to reference original values only
original_df = df.copy()

# Fill missing values for columns starting with "time_from_actual"
time_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('time_from_actual')]

for col in time_cols:
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        if pd.isnull(df.loc[i, col]):
            j = i
            while j < len(df) and pd.isnull(original_df.loc[j, col]):
                previous_actual = df.loc[j - 1, 'Actual']
                previous_time = df.loc[j - 1, col]
                current_actual = df.loc[j, 'Actual']
                difference = previous_time - previous_actual
                df.loc[j, col] = current_actual + difference
                j += 1


Why are your dataframes inserted as images?

In order to provide as much detail as possible. This way, any user who is considering taking a shot at this can easily decide whether to do so or not without taking the time to run the code. Which by the way includes a fully reproducible sample of the data. And I believe the post will be more easily accessible and valuable for future readers.

For each column containing 'time_from_actual':

Create a group for each part of the dataframe where the first row is not null.

Fill the null values with df["Actual"].diff().

Finally, get the cumsum for each group (that's summing the existing value and df["Actual"].diff() for the other rows).


for col in df.filter(like="time_from_actual"):
    g = df[col].notna().cumsum()
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df["Actual"].diff())
    df[col] = df.groupby(g).cumsum()[col]

                  Date  Actual  time_from_actual_1  ...  time_from_actual_6  time_from_actual_7  time_from_actual_8
0  2023-01-01 00:00:00  100.00               97.00  ...               95.00               94.00               93.00
1  2023-01-01 01:00:00   99.72               96.72  ...               94.72               93.72               92.72
2  2023-01-01 02:00:00  101.02               98.02  ...               96.02               95.02               94.02
3  2023-01-01 03:00:00  104.06              101.06  ...               99.06               98.06               97.06
4  2023-01-01 04:00:00  103.60              100.60  ...               98.60               97.60               96.60
5  2023-01-01 05:00:00  103.13              100.13  ...               98.13               97.13               96.13
6  2023-01-01 06:00:00  106.29              103.29  ...              101.29              100.29               99.29
7  2023-01-01 07:00:00  107.82              104.82  ...              102.82              101.82              100.82
8  2023-01-01 08:00:00  106.88              103.88  ...              101.88              100.88               99.88
9  2023-01-01 09:00:00  107.97              104.97  ...              102.97              101.97              100.97
10 2023-01-01 10:00:00  107.04              104.04  ...              102.04              101.04              100.04
11 2023-01-01 11:00:00  106.11              103.11  ...              101.11              100.11               99.11
12 2023-01-01 12:00:00  106.59              103.59  ...              101.59              100.59               99.59
13 2023-01-01 13:00:00  102.77               99.77  ...               97.77               96.77               95.77
14 2023-01-01 14:00:00   99.32               96.32  ...               94.32               93.32               92.32
15 2023-01-01 15:00:00   98.19               95.19  ...               93.19               92.19               91.19
16 2023-01-01 16:00:00   96.17               93.17  ...               91.17               90.17               89.17
17 2023-01-01 17:00:00   96.80               93.80  ...               91.80               90.80               89.80
18 2023-01-01 18:00:00   94.98               91.98  ...               89.98               88.98               87.98
19 2023-01-01 19:00:00   92.15               89.15  ...               87.15               86.15               85.15
20 2023-01-01 20:00:00   95.09               92.09  ...               90.09               89.09               88.09
21 2023-01-01 21:00:00   94.63               91.63  ...               89.63               88.63               87.63
22 2023-01-01 22:00:00   94.77               91.77  ...               89.77               88.77               87.77
23 2023-01-01 23:00:00   91.92               88.92  ...               86.92               85.92               84.92
24 2023-01-02 00:00:00   90.83               90.00  ...               85.00               84.00               83.00
25 2023-01-02 01:00:00   91.05               90.22  ...               85.22               84.22               83.22
26 2023-01-02 02:00:00   88.75               87.92  ...               82.92               81.92               80.92
27 2023-01-02 03:00:00   89.50               88.67  ...               83.67               82.67               81.67
28 2023-01-02 04:00:00   88.30               87.47  ...               82.47               81.47               80.47
29 2023-01-02 05:00:00   87.72               86.89  ...               81.89               80.89               79.89
30 2023-01-02 06:00:00   86.51               85.68  ...               80.68               79.68               78.68
31 2023-01-02 07:00:00   90.22               89.39  ...               84.39               83.39               82.39
32 2023-01-02 08:00:00   90.19               89.36  ...               84.36               83.36               82.36
33 2023-01-02 09:00:00   88.08               87.25  ...               82.25               81.25               80.25
34 2023-01-02 10:00:00   89.72               88.89  ...               83.89               82.89               81.89
35 2023-01-02 11:00:00   87.28               86.45  ...               81.45               80.45               79.45
36 2023-01-02 12:00:00   87.70               86.87  ...               81.87               80.87               79.87
37 2023-01-02 13:00:00   83.78               82.95  ...               77.95               76.95               75.95
38 2023-01-02 14:00:00   81.12               80.29  ...               75.29               74.29               73.29
39 2023-01-02 15:00:00  131.52              130.69  ...              125.69              124.69              123.69


Another version:
def fn(x):
    x.loc[:, "time_from_actual_1":] = (
        x.loc[:, "time_from_actual_1":]
        .fillna(0)
        .add(x["Actual"].diff().fillna(0), axis=0)
        .cumsum()
    )
    return x


out = df.groupby(df["time_from_actual_1"].notna().cumsum(), group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(out)

Prints:
                  Date  Actual  time_from_actual_1  time_from_actual_2  time_from_actual_3  time_from_actual_4  time_from_actual_5  time_from_actual_6  time_from_actual_7  time_from_actual_8
0  2023-01-01 00:00:00  100.00               97.00               99.00               98.00               97.00               96.00               95.00               94.00               93.00
1  2023-01-01 01:00:00   99.72               96.72               98.72               97.72               96.72               95.72               94.72               93.72               92.72
2  2023-01-01 02:00:00  101.02               98.02              100.02               99.02               98.02               97.02               96.02               95.02               94.02
3  2023-01-01 03:00:00  104.06              101.06              103.06              102.06              101.06              100.06               99.06               98.06               97.06
4  2023-01-01 04:00:00  103.60              100.60              102.60              101.60              100.60               99.60               98.60               97.60               96.60
5  2023-01-01 05:00:00  103.13              100.13              102.13              101.13              100.13               99.13               98.13               97.13               96.13
6  2023-01-01 06:00:00  106.29              103.29              105.29              104.29              103.29              102.29              101.29              100.29               99.29
7  2023-01-01 07:00:00  107.82              104.82              106.82              105.82              104.82              103.82              102.82              101.82              100.82
8  2023-01-01 08:00:00  106.88              103.88              105.88              104.88              103.88              102.88              101.88              100.88               99.88
9  2023-01-01 09:00:00  107.97              104.97              106.97              105.97              104.97              103.97              102.97              101.97              100.97
10 2023-01-01 10:00:00  107.04              104.04              106.04              105.04              104.04              103.04              102.04              101.04              100.04
11 2023-01-01 11:00:00  106.11              103.11              105.11              104.11              103.11              102.11              101.11              100.11               99.11
12 2023-01-01 12:00:00  106.59              103.59              105.59              104.59              103.59              102.59              101.59              100.59               99.59
13 2023-01-01 13:00:00  102.77               99.77              101.77              100.77               99.77               98.77               97.77               96.77               95.77
14 2023-01-01 14:00:00   99.32               96.32               98.32               97.32               96.32               95.32               94.32               93.32               92.32
15 2023-01-01 15:00:00   98.19               95.19               97.19               96.19               95.19               94.19               93.19               92.19               91.19
16 2023-01-01 16:00:00   96.17               93.17               95.17               94.17               93.17               92.17               91.17               90.17               89.17
17 2023-01-01 17:00:00   96.80               93.80               95.80               94.80               93.80               92.80               91.80               90.80               89.80
18 2023-01-01 18:00:00   94.98               91.98               93.98               92.98               91.98               90.98               89.98               88.98               87.98
19 2023-01-01 19:00:00   92.15               89.15               91.15               90.15               89.15               88.15               87.15               86.15               85.15
20 2023-01-01 20:00:00   95.09               92.09               94.09               93.09               92.09               91.09               90.09               89.09               88.09
21 2023-01-01 21:00:00   94.63               91.63               93.63               92.63               91.63               90.63               89.63               88.63               87.63
22 2023-01-01 22:00:00   94.77               91.77               93.77               92.77               91.77               90.77               89.77               88.77               87.77
23 2023-01-01 23:00:00   91.92               88.92               90.92               89.92               88.92               87.92               86.92               85.92               84.92
24 2023-01-02 00:00:00   90.83               90.00               89.00               88.00               87.00               86.00               85.00               84.00               83.00
25 2023-01-02 01:00:00   91.05               90.22               89.22               88.22               87.22               86.22               85.22               84.22               83.22
26 2023-01-02 02:00:00   88.75               87.92               86.92               85.92               84.92               83.92               82.92               81.92               80.92
27 2023-01-02 03:00:00   89.50               88.67               87.67               86.67               85.67               84.67               83.67               82.67               81.67
28 2023-01-02 04:00:00   88.30               87.47               86.47               85.47               84.47               83.47               82.47               81.47               80.47
29 2023-01-02 05:00:00   87.72               86.89               85.89               84.89               83.89               82.89               81.89               80.89               79.89
30 2023-01-02 06:00:00   86.51               85.68               84.68               83.68               82.68               81.68               80.68               79.68               78.68
31 2023-01-02 07:00:00   90.22               89.39               88.39               87.39               86.39               85.39               84.39               83.39               82.39
32 2023-01-02 08:00:00   90.19               89.36               88.36               87.36               86.36               85.36               84.36               83.36               82.36
33 2023-01-02 09:00:00   88.08               87.25               86.25               85.25               84.25               83.25               82.25               81.25               80.25
34 2023-01-02 10:00:00   89.72               88.89               87.89               86.89               85.89               84.89               83.89               82.89               81.89
35 2023-01-02 11:00:00   87.28               86.45               85.45               84.45               83.45               82.45               81.45               80.45               79.45
36 2023-01-02 12:00:00   87.70               86.87               85.87               84.87               83.87               82.87               81.87               80.87               79.87
37 2023-01-02 13:00:00   83.78               82.95               81.95               80.95               79.95               78.95               77.95               76.95               75.95
38 2023-01-02 14:00:00   81.12               80.29               79.29               78.29               77.29               76.29               75.29               74.29               73.29
39 2023-01-02 15:00:00  131.52              130.69              129.69              128.69              127.69              126.69              125.69              124.69              123.69


Code
tmp = df.iloc[:, 1:].diff(axis=1).ffill().cumsum(axis=1).add(df['Actual'], axis=0)
out = df.fillna(tmp)

chk with minimal and reproducible example
we need a minimal example and your example is too big. lets create a new example.
example code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Date': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=6, freq='6H'), 'Actual': [100, 98, 50, 40, 80, 50], 'time_from_actual_1': [97.0, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), 90.0, float('nan')], 'time_from_actual_2': [99.0, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), 89.0, float('nan')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


It works in your example, so check it out.

If you have other columns outside of the example and need to extract the actual columns and those that start with 'time_from_actual', use the following code
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith(('Actual', 'time_from_actual'))]
tmp = df[cols].diff(axis=1).ffill().cumsum(axis=1).add(df['Actual'], axis=0)
out = df.fillna(tmp)


check out the code for a slightly different case than the example.
If the observations that occur once a day are not necessarily at 00:00:00, and you need to fill in all NaNs for the day with the difference between them, use the following code
# second example

import pandas as pd
data = {'Date': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=6, freq='6H'), 'Actual': [100, 98, 50, 40, 50, 80], 'time_from_actual_1': [97.0, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), 90.0], 'time_from_actual_2': [99.0, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), 89]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# code
tmp = (df.set_index('Date').diff(axis=1).resample('D').transform('first')
         .cumsum(axis=1).add(df['Actual'].tolist(), axis=0)
         .reset_index()
)
out = df.fillna(tmp)


This is safe code that works in your example and will work in additional situations.
